# How can I prevent frame breaking in Chrome from Google image searches, etc.?

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

More often than not, websites with any number of images will use frame breaking scripts to lose Google Image Search's results frame (e.g. [this relatively benign case](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&sa=N&tbo=d&authuser=0&biw=1202&bih=739&tbm=isch&tbnid=CjXB2H6KhfYxkM:&imgrefurl=http://www.flickr.com/photos/benitopagotto/5783738938/&docid=SKsA0Q1ugTfFIM&itg=1&imgurl=http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2630/5783738938_cb1d90749c_z.jpg&w=600&h=453&ei=rxS5UNXcKaLW2gWLuIDAAw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=4&vpy=132&dur=4640&hovh=195&hovw=258&tx=87&ty=108&sig=109849449660622759530&page=1&tbnh=151&tbnw=190&start=0&ndsp=25&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:87)).  While I somewhat understand the reasons for doing so (as ineloquently put forth by [these people](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/fc7Jwdwo_P0/RCGyOkD-BDAJ)), more often than not, such breakout/redirects dump me to a useless page that doesn't have the image I was looking for, plus it makes going "back" rather irritating as you need to click twice *or more* (some pages jam you through several redirects it seems) in rapid succession.

Other than having reflexes to copy the 'Full-size image' hyperlink quicker than loading the breakout script, is there a way to get my actual result?

Comment: Regarding 'off-topic' votes; where is this best?  This isn't about the web pages themselves (e.g. Web Apps) but the browser, so I figured it goes here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> to stop page loading. You may have to press it multiple times.